# Print a list from a matrix

Tags: prolog

I need a function that given an input of this style:

```
printMatrix(N, M)
```

where `N` is an integer and `M` a list of integers:

```
printMatrix(3, [1,5,8,9 ...]).
```

Where 3 is the number of rows and columns of a board.

The successive integers mark the box number (1 would be equivalent to position 1 (row), 1 (column) of the matrix, 2 the 1,2, 3 the 1,3, 4 the 2,1, 5 the 2 , 2, 6 the 2.3, 7 the 3.1, 8 the 3.2 and 9 the 3.3). You have to paint an 'X' for each number that appears in the list.

The output sought in this example would be the following:

```
-------
| X | | |
-------
| | X | |
-------
| | X | X |
```

I don't even know how to start, any help is welcomed.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more your expected output given certain values of N and M?

Comment: The expected output is a square board N*N, example: 3 means a 3x3 board with 9 boxes.

M is a list that represents each box occupied.
Starting from top-left an integer number, 1 for the 1,1 position, 2 for the 1,2 position, 3 for the 1,3 position ... 3,2 for the 8th box and 3,3 for the 9th box. 

Something like that:


-------
| 1 | | |
-------
| | 5 | |
-------
| | 8 | 9 |

But instead of numbers an 'X' char. 

Thanks damianodamiano.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the index of each box easily. Then iterate over every row and every column and check whether its corresponding index is in the input list, printing the required value along the way (either a 'X' or a ' ', also interleaving the box's walls):

```
printMatrix(N, M):-
  Width is 2*N+1,
  format('~`-t~*|', [Width]),
  forall(between(1,N,Row),
   (
    SBase is N*(Row-1)+1,
    EBase is N*Row,
    nl,
    write('|'),
    forall(between(SBase,EBase,Item),
      (
       (memberchk(Item, M)->write('X');write(' ')),
       write('|')
    ))
  )),
  nl,
  format('~`-t~*|', [Width]).
```

Here I use [forall/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=forall/2) and [between/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=between/3) predicates to iterate over rows and columns, and [memberchk/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=memberchk/2) to see if the item is in the list.

Sample output:

```
?- printMatrix(3,[1,4,5,9]).
-------
|X| | |
|X|X| |
| | |X|
-------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start from something like from this basic solution where the matrix has elements from 0 to 8 in case of 3x3:

```
test:-
    % -------
    % | 0 | 1 | 2 |
    % | 3 | 4 | 5 |
    % | 6 | 7 | 8 |
    N = 3,
    L = [1,5,7],
    NN is N*N,
    write('|'),
    loop(0,NN,N,L).

check_newline(I,_,I):- !.
check_newline(V,Mod,Max):-
    V < Max, !,
    (   0 =:= mod(V,Mod) ->  nl,write('|'); true).

loop(H,H,_,_):- !.
loop(I,Max,N,[]):-
    I < Max, !,
    write('_|'),
    I1 is I+1,
    check_newline(I1,N,Max),
    loop(I1,Max,N,[]).
loop(H,Max,N,[H|T]):-
    H < Max, !,
    write('X|'),
    H1 is H+1,
    check_newline(H1,N,Max),
    loop(H1,Max,N,T).
loop(H,Max,N,[E|T]):-
    H < Max, !,
    H \= E,
    write('_|'),
    H1 is H+1,
    check_newline(H1,N,Max),
    loop(H1,Max,N,[E|T]).

?- test.
|_|X|_|
|_|_|X|
|_|X|_|
true
```

Then you can complicate the code and do all sort of fancy stuff and maybe write shorter code.